# Strange behaviour in size(strfind(n,',')) for n = 44

Tags: matlab

For some reason in

```
size(strfind(n,','))
```

the number `44` is special and produces a comma found result:

```
value={55}
numCommas = size(strfind(value{1},','),2) 
ans= 0 ...(GOOD)

value={44}
numCommas = size(strfind(value{1},','),2)
ans= 1 ...(BAD) - Why is it doing this?

value={'44,44,44'}
numCommas = size(strfind(value{1},','),2)
ans= 2 ...(GREAT)
```

I need to find the number of commas in a cell element, where the element can either be an integer or a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment. The [ASCII code](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) for a comma, (`,`), is 44. Effectively what you are doing in your code is

```
size(strfind(44,','),2)
```

or

```
size(strfind(char(44),','),2)
```

where `44` is not a string but is interpreted as a numeric value which is then converted to a character and results in a comma, (`,`) which we can see when we use [`char`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html)

```
>> char(44)
ans =

,
```

---

You can fix your code by changing

```
value={44}
```

to

```
value={'44'}
```

so then you will be performing [`strfind`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) on a string instead of a numeric value.

```
>> size(strfind('44', ','), 2)
ans =

     0
```

which provides the correct answer.

Alternatively you could use [`num2str`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html)

```
>> size(strfind(num2str(value{1}), ','), 2)
ans =

     0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid this by simply doing `value{1} = '44'`. Or if that's not an alternative, use [`num2str`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) like this:

```
value={44};
numCommas = size(strfind(num2str(value{1}),','),2)    
numCommas =
     0
```

This will also work for string inputs:

```
value={'44,44,44'};
numCommas = size(strfind(num2str(value{1}),','),2)
numCommas =
     2
```

---

Why do you get "wrong" results?`

It's because `44` is the [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/) for comma `,`.
You can check this quite simply by casting the value to [`char`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html).

```
char(44)
ans =
,
```

You are checking for commas in a string. As the input to strfind is an integer, it automatically cast it to char. In the last example, your are inserting a "real" string, thus it finds the two commas in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
value={'44'}
numCommas = size(strfind(value{1},','),2)
```

instead of:

```
value={44}
numCommas = size(strfind(value{1},','),2)
```

It should work, since it's a char now.